# How can I describe multiple result sets from a procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a data access code generation process in place that uses sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set to find the types of columns in result sets. It is working very well for the first result set. However, I would like to expand it to multiple result sets. Is there a reasonable way to accomplish this?

Sample code to look up the result set.

```
SELECT rs.name, rs.is_nullable, t.name AS typeName, rs.max_length, rs.precision, rs.scale
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('
select ''A'' as ColumnA, ''B'' as ColumnB, ''C'' as ColumnC

select ''D'' as ColumnA, ''E'' as ColumnB, ''F'' as ColumnC
', NULL, 1) rs
LEFT JOIN sys.types t ON rs.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
WHERE rs.name IS NOT null
AND t.name <> 'sysname'
```

Currently results in

```
name                                                                                                                             is_nullable typeName                                                                                                                         max_length precision scale
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- --------- -----
ColumnA                                                                                                                          0           varchar                                                                                                                          1          0         0
ColumnB                                                                                                                          0           varchar                                                                                                                          1          0         0
ColumnC                                                                                                                          0           varchar                                                                                                                          1          0         0
```

Please note that two inline select statements are for simple examples. The real procedures would have complex logic and can't be split into multiple procedures.

Comment: As it's name suggests, `dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`, it describes the **first** result set. SQL Server itself has poor internal handling of statements that return multiple result sets. Fortunately, the only place this tends to happen is when using procedures, so those can be easily changes to separate it into separate procedures. For the above, as they are literal statements, just separate it into 2 calls.

Comment: @Larnu In my scenario, I can't break them up into multiple procedures. I was hoping there would be a way to get similar results as this but without the "first" limitation. The code doesn't have any conditional logic around which result sets are returned.

Comment: No, like I said, SQL Server has little to no support for consuming multiple result sets internally.

Comment: No this is not possible. You would need a T-SQL parser, and note that you can never take into account runtime conditions such as `IF` or `WHILE` statements

Comment: [Despite the _dire warnings_ on the documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-fmtonly-transact-sql), you _can still_ use `SET FMTONLY ON;` in all versions of SQL Server today - and it will give you a flat dump of _every possible output result-set_ in a procedure, regardless of any branches within (including things like `MERGE ... OUTPUT` clauses). I use it inside my codegen tools to eliminate the tedium in writing strongly-typed C# classes for sproc result-sets. It isn't perfect, but it still saves me so much time.